# How should I understand this iteration function

Tags: c, iterator

I am working on porting a C FIFO queue implementation into my code and I don't feel comfortable including functions that I don't understand. What does this function do? I see that it returns an integer value, but I don't know what it means. What is the `(*iter)` parameter? I don't see this type declared in the header or implementation file.

You can find the header [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/dtrace/dtrace-78/tools/ctfconvert/fifo.h)
You can find the implementation [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/dtrace/dtrace-78/tools/ctfconvert/fifo.c)

The function in question is copied below:

```
int fifo_iter(fifo_t *f, int (*iter)(void *data, void *arg), void *arg)
{
    fifonode_t *fn;
    int rc;
    int ret = 0;

    for (fn = f->f_head; fn; fn = fn->fn_next) {
        if ((rc = iter(fn->fn_data, arg)) < 0)
            return (-1);
        ret += rc;
    }

    return (ret);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int (*iter)(void *data, void *arg)` is a **function pointer**. When you call `fifo_iter`, you pass it a callback function in the second parameter. This function must have a signature like:

```
int my_callback(void* data, void* arg)
```

This function will then be called for every item in the `fifo_t`. It will be passed the `fn_data` member in the `data` argument.  Whatever you pass for `arg` to `fifo_iter` will also be passed to `iter` as his `arg` argument. This is a common way to just pass generic "context" information through to the callback, without having to resort to ugly, thread-unsafe global variables.

So you can use it like this:

```
int my_callback(void* data, void* arg) {
    printf("my_callback(%p, %p)\n", data, arg);
    return 0;    // always continue
}

void test(void) {
    fifo_t myfifo;    // Needs initialized and populated...

    fifo_iter(&myfifo, my_callback, NULL);
}
```

Additionally, we see that it uses the return value of `iter` in a special way.  First of all, if `iter` ever returns a negative value, the iteration stops immediately, and `fifo_iter` returns -1. This can be an "early failure".  Otherwise, it accumulates the (positive) return values into `ret`, and then returns that value.

Expanding my example. This assumes that the fifo `fn_data` members point to strings.  This will count the total number of capital and lowercase letters in all strings in the FIFO, and also return the total length of all strings.

```
// The context that we'll maintain during the iteration
struct my_context {
    int caps;
    int lowers;
};

// The callback function, called for every string in the FIFO.
int my_callback(void* data, void* arg) {
    const char* str = data;            // Node data is a string
    struct my_context *ctx = arg;      // Arg is my context

    // If any string in the FIFO has a !, abort immediately.
    if (strchr(str, '!'))
       return -1;

    // Update the context to include the counts for this string
    ctx->caps   += count_capital_letters(str);
    ctx->lowers += count_lowercase_letters(str);

    // fifo_iter will accumulate this length
    return strlen(str);
}

// Test driver function
void test(void) {
    fifo_t myfifo;
    struct my_context ctx;
    int total;

    // Assuming these functions exist:
    fifo_init(&myfifo);
    fifo_append(&myfifo, "Stack");
    fifo_append(&myfifo, "Overflow");

    // Initialize the context
    ctx.caps = 0;
    ctx.lowers = 0;

    // Iterate over myfifo, passing it a pointer to the context
    total = fifo_iter(&myfifo, my_callback, &ctx);

    if (total < 0) {
        // Any string had a '!'
        printf("Iteration failed!\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("total=%d caps=%d lowers=%d \n", total, ctx.caps, ctx.lowers);
}
```

If you take a gander through the Linux kernel source code, you'll see this construct all over the place.

For a simple FIFO like we have here, it may not seem worth it. But when you're dealing with more complex data structures like hash lists, and [RCU](https://www.efficios.com/pub/linuxcon-europe-2013/mdesnoyers-userspace-rcu-tutorial-linuxcon-2013.pdf) lists, it makes more sense to maintain the iteration logic in just one place, and utilize callbacks to handle the data in whatever way you need to.

Comment: hello.   I'm trying to add int variables to this fifo. But I only see the same var (this is the last var)    for (int i =0; i<4; i++) {
        int *k = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *k = rand();
        fifo_add(ff, k);
        free(k);
    }    fifo_iter(ff, my_callback, NULL);

Comment: @garrydvaraza If you have a new problem, please ask a new question. The comments are not the right place.

Answer (score 0):

It is iterating over the structure, calling the argument function `iter()` on each element; if an element returns negative, the iteration stops and -1 is returned.